Ping works, but creating new SSH connections fail intermittently
Environment

server OS: Linux  5.15.0-46-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 19:15:44 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

server SSH: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.8

OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020


Describe the problem
Ping the server is OK and stable.
--- ping statistics ---
2607 packets transmitted, 2607 received, 0% packet loss, time 2668547ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.056/0.104/0.580/0.027 ms

The load of the server is  low.
Creating new SSH connections to the server fail intermittently, lasting from one minute to tens of minutes.
But the previously established SSH connection can operate normally, in addition to using SSH related services possibly, such as using the sudo command.
There are three servers with this problem. One  has a more frequent problem and can be inaccessible for up to ten minutes, while the other two have a less frequent problem and are generally inaccessible for one to three minutes.
This problem occurs intermittently and frequently.
Use journalctl -u ssh try to check SSH log but haven't found the reason yet:
Oct 16 16:15:33 user1-SERVER sshd[1806]: debug1: Forked child 3215566.
Oct 16 16:15:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Oct 16 16:15:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
Oct 16 16:15:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 4, 4
Oct 16 16:15:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: Connection from 10.8.238.253 port 65243 on 10.9.74.101 port 22 rdomain ""
Oct 16 16:15:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.8
Oct 16 16:15:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh_0.9.6
Oct 16 16:15:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: no match: libssh_0.9.6
Oct 16 16:15:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 127/65534 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: KEX done [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: userauth-request for user user1 service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "user1"
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "10.8.238.253"
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: userauth-request for user user1 service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: PAM: password authentication accepted for user1
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: do_pam_account: called
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: Accepted password for user1 from 10.8.238.253 port 65243 ssh2
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: monitor_child_preauth: user1 has been authenticated by privileged process
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
Oct 16 16:15:34 user1-SERVER sshd[3215566]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user1 by (uid=0)
Oct 16 16:17:51 user1-SERVER sshd[1806]: debug1: Forked child 3217034.
Oct 16 16:17:51 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Oct 16 16:17:51 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 4, 4
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: Connection from 10.8.238.253 port 65396 on 10.9.74.101 port 22 rdomain ""
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.8
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh_0.9.6
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: debug1: no match: libssh_0.9.6
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 127/65534 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: Received disconnect from 10.8.238.253 port 65396:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: Disconnected from 10.8.238.253 port 65396 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: debug1: do_cleanup
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: debug1: Killing privsep child 3217204
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[3217034]: debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12
Oct 16 16:18:33 user1-SERVER sshd[1806]: debug1: main_sigchld_handler: Child exited
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[1806]: debug1: Forked child 3217248.
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 4, 4
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: Connection from 10.8.238.253 port 65435 on 10.9.74.101 port 22 rdomain ""
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.8
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh_0.9.6
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: no match: libssh_0.9.6
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 127/65534 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: KEX done [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: userauth-request for user user1 service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "user1"
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "10.8.238.253"
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: userauth-request for user user1 service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: PAM: password authentication accepted for user1
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: do_pam_account: called
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: Accepted password for user1 from 10.8.238.253 port 65435 ssh2
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: monitor_child_preauth: user1 has been authenticated by privileged process
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user1 by (uid=0)
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: User child is on pid 3217304
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: session_new: session 0
Oct 16 16:18:37 user1-SERVER sshd[3217248]: debug1: SELinux support disabled

Use ssh -vvv , stuck for tens of minutes after log debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.8 .
user1@user1-SERVER:~$ ssh user1@10.9.74.100 -vvv
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.8, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.9.74.100 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 10.9.74.100 [10.9.74.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.9.74.100:22 as 'user1'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.9.74.100
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:1nBv3wTHcBQrOwbzceVX7cZzkGdjyWfnh3Z+e8hRBAA
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.9.74.100
debug1: Host '10.9.74.100' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user1@10.9.74.100's password: 

How to find the cause, and solve this problem?

Maybe you should using ssh with -vvv option to see if it has any problem and post it here.

@HiếuVũ Added content about "ssh with -vvv option".

What could be worth checking is to use a tunnel on an existing SSH connection to test if the SSH handshake problem also appears on that tunnel. Because right now it looks like a man in the middle interfering with the SSH handshake.

It can also be MTU problems. They can sometimes hamper the initial phase of TCP, while appearing to work fine later on. In that case try lowering the MTU on the server link, to see if that fixes the problem.

@Gerrit Use "ip addr" command to check,  the MTU of ssh client and ssh server both are 1500.

@user9769483 With "ip link" you can see the setting. They default to 1500, but the issue is that routers and bridges in between can have sometimes have lower MTU because they use some encapsulation in a transport. And if ICMP messages are not getting through then the TCP cannot deal with it. Lowering it preemptively on your server link may avoid that problem. "ip link set dev ifname mtu 1475"

It is possible to probe for MTU problems with just ping: ping -s 1472 target-ip-v4 should just be possible with a valid MTU of 1500 across the entire path.
